# Limit definition of the second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm given that a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, and the second derivative $f''(a)$ exists at a point $x=a$. I want to prove that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) + f(a-h) - 2 f(a)}{h^2} = f''(a)$$
Without use of L'Hopital's rule or Taylor's Theorem. I've so far managed to show that
$$f''(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a+h-t) - f(a) + f(a-t)}{ht}$$
And that you may interchange limiting processes $t \to 0$ and $h \to 0$. However, I can't find a way to show that you may take $t \to h$ and $h \to 0$ and end up with the same limit (Which would complete the proof). Can anyone give me a hint on how I could prove that this is valid?

Comment: Mean value theorem is useful here

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got nowhere with the Lagrange form but Cauchy's MVT made things much simpler.

Comment: So were you able to solve it @M.Stevens

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the hint @AdityaDwivedi